# jquery .load() doesn´t work due to the .htaccess file

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I have some dialog window with buttons, on the submit button I call this:

```
$("#delDiv").load("./protected/deleteUser.php?id="+id, function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

Problem is, that my /protected directory is protected with .htaccess file, where I had simply set

> deny from all

so the .load() command doesn´t have access to that file. Is there any way to access that folder of file for this function?

Comment: Nope, if you can't access it normally, you can't access it with ajax.

Comment: Yes I can access it with PHP.

Comment: But with php you access it vía server filesystem not from a browser.

Comment: aha... so is there some way to change the .htaccess to let me access the file via the function but not to let somebody access it by typing it in the URL? Or some workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The solution really depends on framework/application structure. In general I'd suggest to place `deleteUser.php` in publicly available directory, because everything you can call using AJAX will be available to opening directly in browser. In fact, you can check some headers in order to know if request is performed using AJAX or not, but they are very easy to fake.

Also, if you are using any framework, it is better to use its controller+action system, not just a standalone script.