# jquery ajax post 404 not found codeigniter debian

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

Good afternoon, first excuse me for my English, I want to know if can you help me with this Error.

I have a error with my url from jquery-ajax-post:

The error in the firebug is:

> POST .../nomina4/login/validation 404 Not Found x 19ms

1. I work with CodeIgniter + Apache + Debian

> Apache2.conf
>
> AllowOverride All

2. The server have a internal and external ip address
3. The configuration file of Codeigniter is:

> ```
>   $config['base_url'] = '/nomina4/';
>
>   $config['index_page'] = '';
> ```

4. The configuration of the .htaccess for hide index.php

> 

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nomina4/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|styles|scripts|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /nomina4/index.php
</IfModule>
```

6. The script with the inputs user and pwd, this is in the file login_view.php of the folder view.

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> $("#btn").click(function(event) {
>
> ```
>   event.preventDefault();
>
>   $.ajax({
>       url: '<?=base_url()?>login/validation',
>       type: 'post',
>       data: {user: $('#user').val()}
>   })
>   .done(function(data) {
>       console.log(data);
>   })
>   .fail(function(data) {
>       console.log(data);
>   });
> ```
>
> }); // END CLICK BTN
>
> }); // END READY

7. This is the controller

   ```
   class Login extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
   }

   public function index() {
       $data['container'] = 'login_view';
       $data['title'] = 'Iniciar Sesión';
       $this->load->view('template', $data);
   }

   public function validation() {
       $user = $this->input->post("user");
       echo json_encode($user);
   }
   ```

   }

Try channgin the .htaccess and look who has a similar error but not found the solution.

Thanks for the help.

Code side client: views/login_view.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/login_style.css">
<!-- BEGIN LOGIN -->
<div class="login">
    <!-- BEGIN LOGO -->
<div class="logo">
    <!-- <a href="" class="brand"> -->
        <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/img/logo.png" height="280px">
    <!-- </a> -->
</div>
<!-- END LOGO -->
<!-- BEGIN LOGIN -->
<div class="content">
    <!-- BEGIN FORM -->
    <form action="<?=base_url()?>login/validation" class="form-vertical login-form" method="post">
        <h3>Inicio de sesi&oacute;n</h3>
        <br>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div id="msg_user">
                <div class="input-icon left">
                <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                      <input type="text" name="user" id="user" class="input form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="msg_pwd">
                <div class="input-icon left">
                <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                      <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="input form-control" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button class="input btn pull-right" type="submit" id="btn">
            Ingresar
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>
            </button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- END FORM -->
</div>
<!-- END LOGIN -->
<br>

<!-- BEGIN MESSAGE VALIDATION-->
    <div class="message_validation" id="message_validation">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <h5><strong>Mensaje de Error: </strong><div id="message"></div></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- END MESSAGE VALIDATION-->
</div>
<!-- END LOGIN -->

<!-- BEGIN ANIMATION -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("base_url() = "+"<?=base_url()?>");
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url()?>login/validation',
            type: 'post',
            data: {user: $('#user').val()}
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    }); // END CLICK BTN
}); // END READY
</script>
<!-- END ANIMATION -->
```

This is the Crtl + U

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/nomina4/assets/img/logo_ico.jpg">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/nomina4/assets/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>WEBNÓMINAS</title>
</head>
<body><link rel="stylesheet" href="/nomina4/assets/css/login_style.css">
<!-- BEGIN LOGIN -->
<div class="login">
    <!-- BEGIN LOGO -->
<div class="logo">
    <!-- <a href="" class="brand"> -->
        <img src="/nomina4/assets/img/logo.png" height="280px">
    <!-- </a> -->
</div>
<!-- END LOGO -->
<!-- BEGIN LOGIN -->
<div class="content">
    <!-- BEGIN FORM -->
    <form action="/nomina4/login/validation" class="form-vertical login-form" method="post">
        <h3>Inicio de sesi&oacute;n</h3>
        <br>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div id="msg_user">
                <div class="input-icon left">
                <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                      <input type="text" name="user" id="user" class="input form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="msg_pwd">
                <div class="input-icon left">
                <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                      <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="input form-control" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button class="input btn pull-right" type="submit" id="btn">
            Ingresar
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>
            </button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- END FORM -->
</div>
<!-- END LOGIN -->
<br>

<!-- BEGIN MESSAGE VALIDATION-->
    <div class="message_validation" id="message_validation">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <h5><strong>Mensaje de Error: </strong><div id="message"></div></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- END MESSAGE VALIDATION-->
</div>
<!-- END LOGIN -->

<!-- BEGIN ANIMATION -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("base_url() = "+"/nomina4/");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/nomina4/login/validation',
            type: 'post',
            data: {user: $('#user').val()}
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    }); // END CLICK BTN
}); // END READY
</script>
<!-- END ANIMATION --></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I understood "Buenos días", but no such luck with the rest text...

Comment: `die('english please');`

Comment: I have a error in my firebug: post .../nomina4/login 404 not found

I'm using codeigniter + jquery ajax post

My ajax not work and I edit the .htaccess but nothing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not written in English.  Questions posted on StackOverflow must be written using proper English spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter's `$config['base_url']` is for different purposes - [it determines base *URL* part](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html), as you can guess from it's name. I didn't worked with CodeIgniter for some time, but it should detect your base path for itself, and as you are using `RewriteBase`, it should not receive your path base at all. So, check that CodeIgniter is loading for this path, your controller class is in proper place (folder) and loadable by framework.

Comment: Check pleas this, is my similar problem, but not have a solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692595/jquery-load-doesn%C2%B4t-work-due-to-the-htaccess-file